# Apply Generic logic for different types in Java

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I have below given snap of code (two methods) in Java.

Please note, here `Field` is **`java.lang.Field`** and `Method` is **`java.lang.Method`** and I am using `jdk1.7`.

```
/**
     * Apply predicate filter and add into list if it apply(return true)
     * 
     * @param methods list of methods in which method will be added in case predicate returns the true.
     * @param method method which is being to check against the predicate
     * @param predicate the predicate
     */
    private static void applyPredicateForMethods(List<Method> methods, Method method, Predicate<Method> predicate){
        if (predicate == null || predicate.apply(method)) {
            if (!method.isAccessible())
                method.setAccessible(true);
            methods.add(method);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Apply predicate filter and add into list if it apply(return true)
     * 
     * @param fields the list of fields in which method will be added in case predicate returns the true.
     * @param field the field which is being to check against the predicate
     * @param predicate the predicate
     */
    private static void applyPredicateForFields(List<Field> fields, Field field, Predicate<Field> predicate){
        if (predicate == null || predicate.apply(field)) {
            if (!field.isAccessible())
                field.setAccessible(true);
            fields.add(field);
        }
    }
```

Both the methods are doing the same task (Filtering) but for different **`Class/Type/Context`**

Is there any way to make it generic and write the logic at once only?

Comment: I feel like this is the entire point of lambdas and Java 8.

Comment: no, it's not :) I need to use jdk7, otherwise I know how to simplify this with java8 lambda. However thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the generic solution:

```
private static <T extends AccessibleObject> void applyPredicateForFields(List<T> objects, 
                    T object, Predicate<T> predicate){
    if (predicate == null || predicate.apply(object)) {
        if (!object.isAccessible())
            object.setAccessible(true);
        objects.add(object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both are having the super class ( `java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject`) and you are accessing the same methods from that class. Look at the class  [`java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html). Use it as a type.

Answer (score 0):

Both [`java.lang.reflect.Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) and [`java.lang.reflect.Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) extend [`java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html), which provides the method you're using. Just write your code to reference it:

```
private static void applyPredicate
    (List<AccsibleObjects> objects, 
     AccessibleObject object, 
     Predicate<AccessibleObject> predicate) {
    if (predicate == null || predicate.apply(object)) {
        if (!object.isAccessible())
            object.setAccessible(true);
        objects.add(object);
    }
}
```